Are Sobolev–Hölder functions continuous up to the boundary?
Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $k$ be a nonnegative integer, and let $W^{k,p}(U)$ ($1 \leq p < \infty$) be the Sobolev space consisting of all real-valued functions on $U$ whose weak derivatives up to order $k$ are functions in $L^{p}$.
It is well-known that if $n< pk$ and $r+\alpha = k -n/p$ for some $r$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then $W^{k,p}(U)$ embeds into the Hölder space $C^{r,\alpha}(U)$.
Suppose that $W^{k,p}(U)$ does embed into $C^{r,\alpha}(U)$, and let $f \in W^{k,p}(U)$.  Is it then true that $f$ has a (Hölder) continuous extension to the closure of $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
For what it's worth, I am especially interested in the one-dimensional case, i.e., when $U$ is an open interval.

Yes, that is implied. If you look into proofs of these embedding theorems, you can see this: First, the claim is proven for smooth functions. Then using density arguments the claim is proven for Sobolev functions. This density argument implies that the function in question is a.e. equal to a Hoelder continuous functions.
